# View filters are not updated

Tags: 7, views

I have a View filter that contains a list of taxonomy terms; the problem is that when i add new terms to the vocabulary, the new terms are not automatically added to the filter view so i do not see the nodes related to the new terms. Is there a way to link the filter to the vocabulary by saying "all the terms"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the filter for the taxonomy term, try choosing no terms at all instead of choosing all.

Comment: Ops...if i dont't specify a value i get: No valid values found on filter: field_name